# How to speed up this query

Tags: mysql-5, mysql-5.5, myisam

MySQL doesn't have nearest neighbor search so. So I try to come up with a "distance" that's reasonable so the number of returned query is around 20-200. That way innodb doesn't have to compute distance for like 30k rows if we only need 20.

Well, even after that, queries still take 13 seconds.

```
SELECT TB.ID ,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude,
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.185-TB.Latitude,2)+pow(106.773-TB.Longitude,2)*0.98839228980165) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
  MBRContains(
        GeomFromText (
            'MULTIPOINT(-6.1928749092968 106.7651250907,-6.1771250907032 106.7808749093)'
            ),
            TA.Latlong) 
  AND MATCH (TA.FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('re*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND TA.Prominent >15 
ORDER BY
  Distance
```

Number of matches are 32 by the way.

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 32 total, Query took 16.1845 sec)
```

Also an even simpler query where we do not compute distance also take 16 seconds

```
SELECT TB.ID
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
  MBRContains(
        GeomFromText (
            'MULTIPOINT(-6.1928749092968 106.7651250907,-6.1771250907032 106.7808749093)'
            ),
            TA.Latlong) 
  AND MATCH (TA.FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('res*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)    
AND TA.Prominent >15
```

Actually if I do not compute distance query is reasonably fast and I can tell client to compute distance anyway.

I can understand if mysql cannot do nearest neighbor search. What I am doing now is a simple search points in a box here. What am I missing?

The explanation for the query is:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  TA  fulltext    PRIMARY,Prominent,LatLong,LatLong_2,FullTextSearch  FullTextSearch  0       1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  TB  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     752     gensurv_isikota.TA.BusinessID   1   Using index
```

It basically says only one row is computed for each of the process.

number of data is 1.6 million, but number of data in a box is only 30

Similar query without spatial index took 62 seconds.

```
SELECT TB.ID
FROM `tablebusiness` AS TB
JOIN tableauxiliary AS TA ON TA.BusinessID = TB.ID
WHERE TB.Latitude
BETWEEN - 6.1928749092968
AND - 6.1771250907032
AND TB.Longitude
BETWEEN 106.7651250907
AND 106.7808749093
AND MATCH (
TA.FullTextSearch
)
AGAINST (
'res*'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
AND TA.Prominent >15
```

So yea there are improvements by using spatial. But not as well as I wish.

Comment: can you post the EXPLAIN of that query?

Comment: You don't have a full text index, do you?

Comment: Dup of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19998/how-to-interpret-explain-sql/20186#20186

Comment: "Nearest Neighbor" -- an efficient technique: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

Comment: I have fulltext index.

Comment: I have moved on to other queries.

Comment: The problem is that mysql execute the  MATCH (TA.FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('res*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)     first believing it's the most restrictive and there is no way to do otherwise.